# Multiple @RequestParam throwing error in Swagger Editor

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-editor

I have a sprint boot application with REST services and I am using Springfox libraries to generate Swagger json. In that application, I have a POST service which consumes Multipart Form data. I have two @RequestParams in that POST service, where one is MultipartFile and another one is a String parameter which actually consumes json. But When I generate Swagger json, only Multipart file is considered as body param but the other String param is generated as query param which forms the invalid URL. And the POST service is not working as expected

Please refer the service below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "Publish APIs ", notes = "API helps customer to publish their APIs",
        response = DeferredResult.class, responseContainer="ResponseEntity<APIDeploymentResponse")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully API Published "),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request. Validation error occured")})
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<APIDeploymentResponse>> publishAPI(
        @ApiParam(name = "file", value = "API Specification file", required = true)
                @RequestParam MultipartFile file,
        @ApiParam(name = "apiDetails", value = "Required API Information", required = true)
                @RequestParam String apiDetails) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Initiating service to deploy APIs...");

    ApiDetails apidetails = mapper.readValue(apiDetails, ApiDetails.class);

    return serviceRegistryService.apiCreateMode(file, apidetails);

}
```

Below is my POM.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And in POM.xml I have below plugin

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                  <apiSource>
                        <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                        <locations>com.service.registry.controller</locations>
                        <schemes>http,https</schemes>
                        <host>X.X.X.X:8443</host>
                        <basePath>/service-registry</basePath>
                       <info>
                            <title>Services</title>
                            <version>v1</version>
                            <description>Collection of API to Publish, Update and Remove APIs </description>
                            <termsOfService>
                                http://www.github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin
                            </termsOfService>
                            <contact>
                                <email>XXX</email>
                            </contact>
                            <license>
                                <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
                                <name>Apache 2.0</name>
                            </license>
                        </info> 
                        <swaggerDirectory>target/generated-sources/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And below is my Swagger config file.

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
 import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
 import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
 import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;

 import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
 import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
 import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

 @Configuration
 @EnableSwagger2
 public class SwaggerConfig {
 @Bean
 public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            //.apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .build();
}
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(" API")
            .description("List of Services enables customer to work with 
 their API file")
              .version("2.0")
              .build();
     }
 }
```

Part of the Swagger Json which has apiDetails RequestParam as query:

```
 "paths" : {
"/register/api" : {
  "post" : {
    "tags" : [ "register" ],
    "summary" : "Publish APIs ",
    "description" : "API helps customer to publish their API",
    "operationId" : "publishAPI",
    "parameters" : [ {
      "in" : "body",
      "name" : "file",
      "description" : "API Specification file",
      "required" : true,
      "schema" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/MultipartFile"
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "apiDetails",
      "in" : "query",
      "description" : "Required API Information",
      "required" : true,
      "type" : "string"
    } ],
    "responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "description" : "Successfully API Published",
        "schema" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/DeferredResult"
        }
      },
      "400" : {
        "description" : "Bad request. Validation error occured"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I expect to use Swagger json when I have two @RequestParams. But the URL is getting generated as invalid.

https://XXXXXXX.com/YYYYYYY/ZZZZ/register/api?apiDetails={apiDetails}

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method you did specify it to be a `@PathVariable`

```
@ApiParam(name = "apiDetails", value = "Required API Information", required = true)
       @PathVariable String apiDetails)
```

it should be a `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`

---

Alternatively if you intend to use `@PathVariable`, it expects you having the post mapping somthing like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/" + "{apiDetails}"})
```

Comment: Sorry. It is @RequestParam only. I tried different things before posting here and pasted the same thing here. Corrected the code again

Comment: can you clarify the end goal? is your purpose to pass them both as body params? or you want them both to be query params? if you want them to be in body params annotate them with `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`